# How do I decrease number of frames in OpenCV python?

Tags: python, opencv

I'm using python and opencv to work with the frame. I'm following the code below which saves frame in a directory. I have a problem that even if the video is 1 second I get more than 1000 frames.

Can anyone help me how to decrease the number of frames?

```
import cv2
import os 
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('7.mp4') 
currentFrame = 0
ret, frame = cap.read()
current_dir=os.getcwd()
while ret:
 name = current_dir+'/pic2/frame' + str(currentFrame) + '.jpg'
 print(name)
 cv2.imwrite(name,frame)
 currentFrame+=1
```

Comment: Your code just reads one frame, and then forever writes it into files with an increasing sequence number...

Comment: then how can I read the next frame?  Sorry but I'm a beginner in programming

Comment: Then you need practice, practice, practice. Begin by formulating the algorithm for the task in words. Let the video be a stack of photos, and file be a labeled envelope with a photo inside. What step-by-step instructions would you give to someone so they end up with the result you want? Once you have that, implement it in a programming language.

Answer (score 0):

You are reading 1 frame and then, because `ret==True`, you are in an infinite loop, saving the same frame over and over. As you can see on the [tutorials](https://docs.opencv.org/master/dd/d43/tutorial_py_video_display.html), you should do something like this:

```py
import os
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('7.mp4') 

currentFrame = 0
current_dir = os.getcwd()
while True:                   # infinite loop
    ret, frame = cap.read()   # read frame-by-frame
    if not ret:               # if read fails
        break                 # break the loop
    name = os.path.join(current_dir, 'pic', 'frame{}.jpg'.format(currentFrame))
    print(name)
    cv2.imwrite(name, frame)
    currentFrame += 1

cap.release()
```